# SQL injection fixing in PHP

Tags: php, sql, content-management-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection)

I would like to fix a SQL injection in appRain CMS:
http://code.google.com/p/apprain-quickstart/downloads/list

If someone could help me out, in which php file to look and give me the right function, then it would be great.

I've tried to use mysql_real_escape_string, but i can not find the correct function where to use it.

exploit: http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/520911

OR: /profile/-1 union all select 1,2,3,version(),5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Read the links you have given properly.

The solution to the problem is written in the link

1.
Use the prepared statement class to fix the sql injection vulnerability & filter sql error requests.
Set error(0) to prevent against information disclosure via exceptions or error reports.

2.
Parse the input fields and restrict characters like () > < \ / etc to prevent against script inclusion.
Parse also the vulnerable output sections were the script code is getting executed out of the module context.

**To Make a prepared statement**

```
$oDB=new PDO('..your connection.. ');
$hStmt=$oDB->prepare("select * from users where id=:id");
$hStmt->execute(array(':id',$userID));
```

Notice above that `$userID` is not combined with the SQL string therefore an SQL injection will not work on it.

**Using mysqli_real_escape_string**

Note that `mysql_real_escape_string` has been depreceated so instead I'll mention how to use `mysqli_real_escape_string`

```
$a= "'ABCD"; //will not work because of quotation

$a= $mysqli->real_escape_string($a);
   //Now this is the string with special chars escaped
```

For more information read

PDO  [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Escaping Strings http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: This is not an answer, the resource you quote is linked in the question. The rest is comment material.

Comment: Fair enough. I edited it to describe how to do it. :-) Cheers

Comment: Not really necessary in my eyes, but have fun. Too much of the love maybe because this Q might be getting deleted soon.

Comment: Well, first of all, thanks for the quick response.
Second of all, if you can't read the code well, like I can't, I don't see point in posting just to get some rep. I've tried for many days now, I just can't find the right function. "Leave the work to professionals". That was kind of a dumb thing to say, cause you can't get to pro level, without trying @hakre. 

Thanks to Carl, but in my opinon, filtering sql errors is not a working fix, because that is not a SQL error, that is a real working SQL injection, nothing to do with SQL errors.

Comment: @user1676106 SQL injection is not something you can fix, its just something to try to prevent. And both these methods will prevent it to a large degree. Filtering the string you provide to SQL seems the only option I have heard about so I'm not sure what you meant by "that is not a SQL error, that is a real working SQL injection, nothing to do with SQL errors."